# Limit of multiple variables function

Tags: calculus

How can I find limit of $\frac {x^{\frac 13}y^2}{(x+y^3)}$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the limit from the path

$$x=\frac{m^3}{n^3},\quad y=\frac1n,\quad n\to\infty$$

Then it is equal to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{m}{n\cdot n^2}}{\frac{m^3}{n^3}+\frac{1}{n^3}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{mn^3}{n^3(m^3+1)}=\frac{m}{m^3+1}$$

As the value of your limit depends on the parameter $m$, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Interesting path for a multivariable limit!